# How to anonymize URL in application insights?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights, appinsights

I have URL `/users/myuser@gmail.com`.  I don't want to log the actual email in the logs. What can I do?

I really like to be logged like `/users/m***r@gmail.com` but I just don't know if it is possible and how.

### Update

It is a c# on ASP.net core 3.1 framework.

Comment: what's kind of you project? like .net core web or something else?

Comment: @IvanYang It is on dotnet core 3.1. Updated the question as well :+1:

Comment: You can try it with the [ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer), to see if the url can be modified there.

Comment: Would guess it's possible by implementing your own `ITelemetryProcessor` and adding it with `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<YourTelemetryProcessor>()`

Comment: @AshkanSirous, if you still have more issues, please let me know. And if it's helpful, please accept it as answer:).

Comment: @IvanYang Thanks man. I was actually testing it and wondering if I can write a smaller version of it. But basically your solution is awesome! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer) to modify it.

I write a sample code snippet for asp.net core. For testing purpose, I just replace the information(like the email) in the url. Please feel free to change it to meet your need.

1.Add a new class, and implement it with the following code:

```
public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
       
        if (requestTelemetry == null) return;

        if (requestTelemetry.Url.ToString().Contains("Home"))
        {
            string str1 = requestTelemetry.Url.ToString();

            //for test purpose, it is just replaced here.
            Uri uri = new Uri(requestTelemetry.Url.ToString().Replace("Home", "myhome222"));
            requestTelemetry.Url = uri;

            //it will also be shown in the Name and Operation_name, you should write your logic to do that.
            //requestTelemetry.Name = "";
            //requestTelemetry.Context.Operation.Name = "";
        }         
        
    }
}
```

2.in the Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices method,register the ITelemetryInitializer:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

        //use this line of code to register.
        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyTelemetryInitializer>();
    }
```